# Ответ на вопрос, взятый у другого пользователя из комментария

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, ответы

Иногда можно встретить комментарии под вопросом с уже правильным ответом, за который пользователи голосуют, а спустя некоторое время появляется ответ от другого пользователя, который берёт в ответ идею из комментария.

- С одной стороны люди, не знакомые со структурой ruSO и пришедшие, например, из поисковиков, могут не заметить/не понять комментарий, и увидеть сразу ответ, что будет полезней для них.
- С другой стороны, это можно списать на набивание себе рейтинга, ведь в качестве ответа можно попросить дать того, кто написал комментарий.

Как быть в таких ситуациях?

[Пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512106/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: ответы должны быть в ответах, так что все нормально

Comment: ...ответил @Grundy в комментарии :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, что не мешает вам сделать из моего комментария свой ответ ;-)

Comment: Для таких случаев, в ответе есть галочка "общий"

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, мне кажется галочка "общий" совсем для других случаев :)

Comment: @Grundy, для других. но и для этих тоже. Перенося комментарий в ответ вы, все-таки, не становитесь его автором

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я точно помню, что подобный вопрос уже задавался :-) надо поискать

Comment: А разве, если спрашивающий отблагодарил ответившего в комментариях, ответивший не может продублировать этот ответ с комментов в "ответы"? Итак же какое-то время проходит. А если ответившему лень писать дубликат в "ответы", почему другой не может? И как написали выше, если человек зайдёт с поисковика на страницу, он может и не увидеть коммент, особенно, когда комментов много или зашедший - новичок на SO

Comment: @zayn1991, тут вопрос скорее не в может/не может, а в авторстве и не вполне заслуженной карме

Comment: Эм, надеюсь, никто не против, что я у кого-то [стырил значок](http://i.imgur.com/1polY0U.png)? .-.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а карму присуждает задавший вопрос, человек. Если он явно видит "воровство", пусть не голосует. А вообще, я бы в инструкции этот пунктик жирным выделил, дабы осведомить людей

Comment: @D-side, всё, грешник ты! клеймо на тебе!)

Comment: @zayn1991, не только и не столько ТС, сколько сообщество, голосуя за и против

Comment: в сообществе есть человек, который *ленится* давать полноценный ответ, и довольно часто оставляет его(ответ) в комментарии, на просьбы об оформлении полноценного ответа можно услышать: *Мне лень...*

Comment: @Bald давайте *будем* показывать пальцем ;-)

Comment: @Bald, на самом деле тут таких много.

Comment: @avp все мы грешны(я тоже бывает так делаю) и я нисколько не буду против если кто то мой коммент преобразует в ответ и соответственно получит за это бонус в виде *репы*.

Comment: @KromStern, самый известный бопох мне кажется :):):)

Comment: Спросите себя, делает ли публикация ответа сайт лучше (не важно кто автор) или нет. Рассуждения о мотивации на основе репутации не имеют к этому отношения и в целом являются токсичными.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Переносить *ответ* в ответ и отмечать "общим", либо улучшать и дополнять

Если человек намеренно отказывается от получения репутации за свой ответ (как в плюс, так и в минус), то значит ему вобщем-то и всё равно, что с его ответом сделают.

С другой стороны, тот кто ответ просто скопировал, тоже может не заслуживать за него баллов - он же просто подсмотрел и скопипастил ответ. Результат переноса - как раз "общий" труд двух человек - ответившего и наведшего порядок.

Если же краткий ответ перенесен и существенно дополнен/расширен/улучшен, тот тут уже награда в виде баллов вполне себе уместна.

Comment: я не призываю *плюсовать* перенесенные ответы из коментов(так же я считаю что и минусы тут не совсем уместны), но уж лучше будет перенесенный ответ, чем он так и останется в комменте. все Выше сказанное IMHO

Comment: @Bald во многом с вами согласен, просто переформулировал на свой лад

Comment: 1- нет необходимости делать ответ общим: не нужно от ответственности уходить—исходный  комментарий мог неверный ответ содержать. 2- Не необходимости дополнять/расширять/улучшать (если ответ и так нормальный, то можно всегда улучшить, но необязательно)—уже тот факт, что ответ опубликован как ответ (можно голосовать, комментировать, легче и быстрее на странице найти) уже улучшает сайт.

Comment: А не подскажете как ответ пометить общим? Вдруг пригодится, в будущем

Comment: @Herrgott при публикации ответа есть соответствующий пункт

Answer (score 14):

В дополнение к другим ответам: **нужно различать ситуации**, когда один пользователь после долгого выяснения деталей и предложения нескольких решений в конце концов приходит к решению, которое удовлетворяет автора вопроса, но кто-то другой **успевает быстрее оформить решение в виде ответа**; и когда кто-то намеренно игнорирует механику работы сайта по той или иной причине и даёт полноценный ответ в комментарии, но кто-то решает **перенести решение в ответ, чтобы его было легче найти**.

- В первом случае автор ответа, очевидно, поступает нечестно. Следовало бы дождаться, когда автор решения сам оформит решение в виде ответа. Если он это делает, то имеет смысл обратиться к модератору, чтобы тот удалил дубликат.
- Во втором случае надо смотреть на мотивацию того, кто дал решение в комментарии.

  - Если мотивация "ну это же тривиальный вопрос!", то можно с чистой совестью копировать решение в ответ, потому что это выпендрёж отдельно взятого пользователя.
  - Мотивация может быть "так будет легче удалить вопрос": если вопрос оффтопичен, то можно дать краткую отписку, чтобы как-то помочь автору вопроса, но всё равно способствовать закрытию и удалению вопроса, а это делать проще, если нет заплюсованного или принятого ответа.
  - Наконец, не у всех есть время давать подробные и развёрнутые ответы, поэтому они могут подкинуть идею, которая поможет автору вопроса, но сами не удостоверятся в том, что решение подходит, и не будут реализовывать его полностью. У вас есть возможность дать полный ответ на базе этой идеи.

Так или иначе, всегда надо стремиться давать развёрнутые ответы. Просто так скопировать из комментария часто недостаточно, следует дополнить решение деталями.

И если копируете чужое решение, то правилом хорошего тона будет сослаться на автора, если, конечно, вы сами не написали бы то же самое, как часто может быть в случае простых вопросов. Отмечать ли скопированный из комментария ответ общим — на ваше усмотрение, зависит от количества заимствованного материала и объёма ваших дополнений.

Answer (score 10):

На мой взгляд, если автор комментария осознанно не оформляет ответ, а оставляет комментарий и кто то из участников сообщества оформляет его в соответствии с правилами, то почему бы ему не получить за это *бонус* в виде *репутации*.

Да с моральной стороны вполне логично было бы сделать такой ответ *общим*, но я считаю что это должно быть целиком и полностью на совести *отвечающего*, единственное что я считаю делать обязательно в таком случае так это добавлять в *ответ* указание *автора*.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, все как бы замалчивают о еще одном обстоятельстве, которое приводит к подобной ситуации - это когда сам автор комментария боится оказаться не правым (выглядеть глупо) и боится, что его рейтинг будет понижен. Таким образом, он пытается перестраховаться. И, в таком случае, абсолютно правильным видится то, что кто-то его опередил и разместил ответ. Если не уверен - не лезь и не плачься потом по данному поводу с киванием на моральную сторону. При этом автор комментария не только не был уверен, но и еще игнорировал тем самым правила сайта.

Говорить о том, что кто-то долго выяснял в комментариях что да к чему в вопросе... Ну так и автор "украденного" ответа не сможет дать таковой без уточнений. Если такая ситуация и была - то это скорее редкость (и удача того, кто дал ответ).

Также есть еще одна ситуация - банально большинство не читает комментариев. Можно пытаться доказывать сколь угодно обратное, но факт останется фактом. И давая ответ, часто просто человек "спешит" его дать, не читая комментариев. Также, человек давая ответ, пытается где-то что-то отформатировать и время, затрачиваемое на его (ответа) размещение уходит больше. А за это время уже кто-то настрочил (игнорируя правила сайта) свой ответ в комментариях.

Поэтому, мне кажется, что в любом случае "вина" лежит исключительно на том, кто строчит ответ в комментарии. А если еще и в целом абстрагироваться от каких-то личных амбиций, то чем мы занимается на этом сайте? Меряемся писюнами (рейтингами) или стараемся оказать помощь другим?

Answer (score 2):

На Хэшкоде была по этому поводу логичная функция: "превратить комментарий в ответ". Думаю, зря это убрали из функционала `SO`, какими бы благозвучными мотивы для этого ни были.

Comment: Вы всегда это можете сделать *ручками*: создать ответ, перенести информацию из комментария, сделать общим.

Comment: Не то чтобы это убрали из функционала SO – скорее, не добавили )

Comment: "Вы всегда это можете сделать ручками" -- конечно можем, но не будем. Плагиатом заниматься нехорошо (а неплагиатом - лениво). А вот если прохожий увидит заплюсованный комментарий и сделает его ответом - вполне себе так хороший поступок, да и автору будет сигнал расширить тезис до ответа, раз уж он привлек какое-то внимание.

Comment: " скорее, не добавили )" -- насколько я помню, движок Хэшкода - это молодой движок SO, так что скорее все же убрали.

Answer (score 2):

Если человек смог разобраться в чем состоит вопрос, и дал грамотный ответ - пускай и чужой, то он и так знает, как это работает.

Уча других учимся мы сами, поэтому если даже предположить, что этот человек не знал ответа, но смог разобраться в чужом - то он уже чему-то научился, и помог другому. Награждать возможно, и не нужно, но и в отрицательную сторону уводить тоже не стоит.

Вместо того, что-бы самому расписывать ответ, он "загуглил" через другой комментарий.

Сомневаюсь, что человек незнакомый с javascript полезет искать чужие ответы, и выдавать за свои.

К тому же, сам смысл сообщества(на мой взгляд) как раз-таки и состоит в помощи.