# Что делать с вопросом, на который дали ответ в комментарии к вопросу?

Tags: поддержка

Доброго времени суток!

Есть следующий вопрос: [C# MVC. Использование ViewModel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666893/c-mvc-%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-viewmodel).

На данный вопрос дали ответ в комментариях. Как его правильно закрыть? Неужели мне придется писать ответ на собственный вопрос? Или есть другие способы?

Comment: `Неужели мне придется писать ответ на собственный вопрос?` - а почему нет? это не запрещено.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я знаю, что не запрещено, но просто есть 2 причины, по которым у меня нет желания писать ответ на собственный вопрос: 1) время, необходимое для оформления ответа; 2) совесть не позволяет их ответ копипастить, ведь по сути не я отвечал на свой вопрос, а они ответили на мой.)

Comment: ruSO - база знаний. В которой на вопросы ищут ответы. Кто-то пишет ответ в комментарии, тем самым не помогая остальным пришедшим на ресурс ( сам грешу кстати этим :( ). В результате может вам помогли, а десяткам-сотням другим - нет. Они сами так решили. А вы, как раз-таки, можете поделиться сим приобретенным знанием с другими. Совесть должна сказать: как же так, я узнал, как это делается, а другие не узнают.))

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/186999)

Comment: Причина "время" - довольно странная. Т.е. вам жалко времени для оформления ответа на ваш же вопрос - а остальным пользователям должно быть его не жалко на то же самое действие? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вопрос "свежий", стоит предложить ответившему оформить полноценный ответ. Если он не отреагирует в течение продолжительного времени, ничто не мешает оформить ответ самому.

> совесть не позволяет их ответ копипастить, ведь по сути не я отвечал на свой вопрос, а они ответили на мой

В знак уважения к ответившему можно упомянуть его в ответе и пометить ответ как "общий".

Comment: и/или  лучше... ибо В знак уважения к ответившему можно упомянуть его в ответе, но репку можно и заработать, раз тот не захотел )

Comment: Надо было ответить в комментарии, а вы бы заработали репку... Хотя нет)

Comment: у меня я сделал так же в итоге ктото пожаловался и ответ удалили

Comment: @AndreiKhotko ну вообще-то предполагается что вы сразу будете искать вопрос по сети(не только ruSO, но вообще по сетям Stackechange по типу enSO, jaSO, ptSO, Super User, и по другим сетям StackExchange и в самом интернете, собственно говоря), прежде чем самому задавать вопрос.