# Комментарии как ответы

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, комментарии

Вижу очень много комментариев, которые по сути являются ответами, но комментаторы по каким-то причинам не оформляют их в виде ответов.

Все бы ничего, но это в общем ухудшает читаемость ресурса. Ведь по сути комментарии были придуманы, для того, чтобы уточнить вопрос или обсудить ответ, но они ведь не заменители ответов.

Не помню есть ли в инструментах модератора, оформить комментарий в виде ответа или нет - раньше что-то такое точно было.

Как быть?

1. Поднимать тревогу, чтобы модератор оформил в виде ответа
2. Просить комментатора оформить в виде ответа (в 90% случаев он все равно не оформит в виде ответа)
3. что то еще.

Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: и два дня назад тоже уже спрашивали https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5225/191482  ))

Comment: Часто пишу комментарии почти ответы, когда лень или нет времени оформлять полноценный ответ. Если кто-то на основе моего комментария напишет ответ - я только "за". Причём упоминать меня не надо.

Comment: Неделя ответов в виде комментариев на ru.so.