# Нормально, когда ответ из одного слова набирает 4 балла?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

[Вот принятый ответ на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011647/340492), набравший 4 балла (и -1 от меня), состоящий из одного слова, оставленный через 4 часа после моего комментария, в котором дан более полный ответ на этот вопрос! Под ним есть мои комментарии, лучше описывающие ситуацию.

Как вы считаете, это нормально?

Comment: Простите, но на мете есть пяток тем, в которых разбирается вопрос о том, что делать, если ответ дан в комментариях (шепотом: переносить в ответ), например см. [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5225/213987) и есть нытьё по поводу старичков, которые ограничиваются тем, что пишут комментарии в ответ, давая новичкам возможность набрать рейтинг. Так что вам надо было просто сразу давать ответ, а не отвечать в комментарии. А потом уже - извините, "поезд ушёл". Так что совет на будущее: уверены, что знаете ответ - пишите в ответ.

Comment: @AK не думал, что кто-то будет таким наглым, чтобы написать ответ из одного слова после моего коммента. Но больше всего меня поражает, сколько репутации он получил за свой ответ. Кто вообще в здравом уме будет голосовать за такой ответ?

Comment: Никакой наглости тут нет. Вы же не застолбили и не запатентовали правильный ответ? Странно считать, что если я на ответ 2+2 напишу 4 в комментарии, то это должно заблокировать всех остальных от возможности дать свой ответ.

Comment: P.S. Уточните вопрос пожалуйста. А то заголовок об одном, а тело о другом.

Comment: @Kromster слишком длинный заголовок получится.

Comment: @Kromster ну вообще-то это правильно. Если вы ответили на вопрос, то кто даёт право другим людям вас плагиатить?

Comment: Разница в том, что вы не ответили, а прокомментировали. Предлагаю "По мотивам моего комментария написали ответ. Это нормально?"

Comment: Ожидал увидеть ниже ответ "Да, нормально".

Comment: Раз народу нравится краткость (плюсуют же), значит нормально.

Comment: К сожалению, норма - это не всегда хорошо.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия что вы предлагаете сделать в этом случае? Запретить постить ответ, по смыслу хотя бы косвенно соответствующий "не нужно" всем другим участникам? На каком основании? Только потому, что вы высказали такое же мнение в комментариях? "не нужно" - это же единственный правильный вариант ответа, так что вы предлагаете запретить другим участникам отвечать на этот вопрос. Вопрос должен висеть без ответа исключительно потому, что вы "застолбили" суть ответа где-то в комментарии? Если вы хотели ответить - стоило написать ответ, а не комментарий. Не написали - не нойте :)

Comment: Пфф https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/259976

Comment: "_Но больше всего меня поражает, сколько репутации он получил за свой ответ_" - не стоит удивлятся, вы сами своим постом здесь сделали ему великолепную рекламу.

Comment: @0xdb не знаете, здесь можно оскорблять людей, не указывая конкретно или сообщество? Потому что мне хочется. У ответа уже 7 плюсов... Думал, что на сайте, населённом программистами, адекватных людей больше, чем в повседневной жизни.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, ну что вы, в самом деле, подумайте, разве обычный, адекватный окружающей нас реальности человек добровольно займется таким сложным делом как программирование? Да никогда. Так что, похоже, вы забрели не в ту компанию...

Comment: Вероятно, хотелось чтобы ответ был подлиннее? Типа как вот в c# подобный вопрос спрашивали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/697246/213987

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Вы хотите добавить ответ?

Comment: Было бы хорошо вопрос не просто открыть, но исправить. Я, кстати,емнип, голосовал за закрытие с причиной "непонятна суть вопроса". Как писал выше - тело вопроса про краткость, а комментарии и обсуждение - про копипасту.

Comment: @Kromster переоткрыл. Вообще удивительно, порой на мете люди вопросы закрывают с ещё большим рвением, чем на основном сайте =/

Comment: @Suvitruf, я голосовал за закрытие, потому что в ходе развития событий вскрылся подтекст не обозначенный в вопросе и мне стало непонятным о каком `это нормально?` идет речь. Хотя изначально поддержал автора в плане неприятия коротких и не информативных ответов.

Comment: @Suvitruf не путайте пожалуйста, я неоднократно просил ТС отредактировать и уточнить вопрос. Вопрос неясен. Флаг за закрытие - это еще более веское указание для ТС, что минимум 5 людям вопрос неясен, и наверно, его действительно надо уточнить.

Comment: @Kromster уточнить надо, но зачем так рваться закрыть?

Comment: @Suvitruf а как вы предлагаете мотивировать ТС уточнять еще? ) В комментариях просьбы неоднократны, голоса за закрытие накапливаются (но закрытие не происходит до 5 штук), появление метки "требует правки"..

Comment: @Kromster я думаю, ТС ещё в самом начале всё понял, просто встал в позу)

Comment: Интересно что тут еще и Эффект Стрейзанд сработал, что позволило ответу набрать плюсиков. Мне кажется, до появления этой темы, на том ответе была всего пара голосов :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP 3 или 4 плюса было изначально.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну а стало 9, обычно столько не набирают :)

Comment: Зачем вы испортили вопрос скриншотами?

Comment: Адекватный человек не будет страдать и возмущаться целую неделю из-за того, что за якобы его счет кто-то другой получил какие-то циферки.

Answer (score 9):

Нормально

Comment: Настолько толсто, что даже слишком тонко

Comment: Но ведь [такой ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9441/%d0%9d%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-4-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0/9443#comment39116_9441) уже есть в комментариях.

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, и это тоже нормально :)

Comment: @Kromster После Вашего ответа эта дискуссия достаточно хорошо демонстрирует насколько допустимы односложные ответы и как сообщество может на это реагировать.

Comment: Отнюдь. Посмотрите по ссылке из поего ответа - из 134 ответов заминусованых очень мало.

Comment: @Kromster Я имел ввиду что если с коротким ответом что-то не так, то участники могут проголосовать и опубликовать более развернутые ответы. Так сообщество может отрегулировать ситуацию.

Comment: Но, иногда с коротким ответом "все так" )

Answer (score 8):

> Нормально, когда ответ из одного слова набирает 4 балла?

Мы не контролируем голоса других. Если они поставили +4 - это вопрос к ним. Я вполне вижу ситуацию с очень плохим, но очень популярным вопросом предполагающим очень короткий и очень емкий ответ, получающим и +20. ([134 ответа с ruSO длиной до 24 символов включая разметку](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/1091806/1348188/short-answers))

С одной стороны на SO есть ограничение на минимальную длину ответа. Т.е. мы вправе полагать, что короткие ответы активно не приветствуются. С другой стороны, на них нет запрета, и они могут собирать плюсы. Нормально ли это - в целом да. Хорошо ли это - в целом нет. Все же миссия SO это не совсем вопросы и ответы (иначе бы мы тут составили базу всех арифметических сумм пар чисел от 0 до гугла, с ответами). Цель SO это вопросы и объяснения. А хорошее объяснение - занимает некоторый объем.

---

Далее в вопросе и комментариях вы меняете тему вопроса на

> не думал, что кто-то будет таким наглым, чтобы написать ответ из одного слова после моего коммента ... Если вы ответили на вопрос, то кто даёт право другим людям вас плагиатить?

1. Никакой наглости и плагиата тут нет. Вы же не застолбили и не запатентовали правильный ответ? Странно считать, что если я на вопрос "Сколько будет 2+2?" напишу 4 в комментарии, и это должно было бы заблокировать всех остальных от возможности дать ответ. Может они комментарии и не читали даже.
2. Если же даже комментарий перенесли в ответ 1 к 1, то тут скорее промах того кто комментарий писал. Почему он сам его не разместил ответом? Отвечу за себя - я пишу ответы и подсказки к вопросам в комментариях, когда у меня нет времени все как следует расписывать. Я полагаю что комментарий А - поможет автору вопроса, и Б - будет кем-то взят для составления/улучшения своего ответа.
3. И да, правила хорошего тона, при переносе комментария в ответ, дополнить и расширить его, указать авторство (т.к. комментарий может быть удален) и отметить "общим".

Comment: Нету отметки "общий" в правилах хорошего тона. Писать ответы - тоже труд, и он должен быть вознаграждён репутацией.

Comment: "правила хорошего тона" - подразумевает, что это не строгие правила

Comment: Давайте отбросим вариант, что человек не читал комментарии. Такого не бывает. Если после вашего комментария он написал ответ и получил за него репутацию, это нечестно. За что ему репутация, если он не приложил никаких усилий для того, чтобы дать ответ? Я считаю, что ответ (в ответе или комментарии) является интеллектуальной собственностью. Представьте, что по вашей же логике, кто-то скопирует не комментарий, а ответ.

Comment: Превосходно бывает. Не придумывайте :-) Ответ в комментарии не является ответом, т.к. это комментарий ;-) А про интеллектуальную собственность, не преувеличивайте, а то я сейчас объявлю все буквы своего комментария своими и запрещу вам их употреблять :-P Куда бы вы хотели скопировать мой ответ?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, так вас оказывается просто жаба давит. Тайтл для ссылки добавить комментарий `Используйте комментарии для запроса дополнительной информации или предложения улучшений. Избегайте публикации ответа на вопросы в комментариях.` Какие тут еще могут быть вопросы?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия "_Давайте отбросим вариант, что человек не читал комментарии. Такого не бывает._" - нет, давайте не будем отбрасывать, бывает, и намного чаще, чем вам кажется. Комментарии не являются неотемлимой частью вопросов или ответов. Зачем они нужны? Уже ответил комментатор выше. Я, например, их вообще никогда не читаю, ну только иногда, если они @ мне адресованы.

Answer (score 4):

В подавляющем большинстве случаев хороший ответ должен быть более информативным, но и тут есть нюансы.

1. Полезен вопрос или нет, решает каждый участник сам с помощью голосования, и это право каждого решать, что полезно, а что — нет, вне зависимости от контента.
2. Никто вас не останавливает проголосовать против плохого ответа и написать свой, более высокого качества.
3. Слишком подробный ответ может быть также менее полезен, чем лаконичный ответ (я имею ввиду ответы больше чем одно слово, разумеется).
4. Это намного лучше, чем ответы в комментариях, для которых они не предназначены правилами данного сообщества.
5. Дать скупой ответ намного лучше, чем оскорблять или даже упрекать других участников, что также запрещено правилами сообщества.
6. Какой вопрос — такой ответ или всё познаётся в сравнении. В данном случае, можно было бы больше написать, чем одно слово, но для данного вопроса и такой ответ адекватен, так как технически является полноценным ответом.

Answer (score 3):

я так и не понял функциональную особенность рейтинга, возможно не сильно проникся, но все же. Жизнь состоит из соревнований, ячеек опыта, но не кажется ли, что все это навязано обществом.

Нет, нет, я ни в коем случае не пытаюсь сказать что надо что-то менять вокруг, изменить систему, выбирать ответ из комментариев и т.д.

Постарайтесь изменить свое отношение к данному сообществу, ведь не рейтинг наполняет его, а люди. Все здесь собрались, ради одной лишь цели, оказать поддержку нуждающимся и лишь в определенной сфере. это не соревнование вовсе.

Так что если комментарий/ответ помог с решение проблемы, можно считать что предназначение исполнено и ситуацию можно отпустить.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза "Нет, не нужно" не обладает достаточной степенью оригинальности, чтобы говорить о плагиате или нарушении авторских прав. Susanin имел право опубликовать такой ответ, хотя этот ответ и полностью бесполезен. Смысл сайта - не дать как можно больше формально "правильных" ответов, а увеличить количество полезной информации по программированию в русскоязычном интернете. Почему не нужно импортировать? Для тех, кто переучивается с языка с другими принципами взаимодействия модулей, например С++, это далеко не очевидно. Хороший ответ как минимум мог бы объяснить суть понятия пакета и директивы import со ссылкой на документацию или онлайн-учебник, как максимум - привести цитаты из спецификации языка не этот счет. На простые вопросы можно и нужно давать качественные ответы, а не поминать каждый раз "кэпа"; пока не придет понимание этого, люди так и не будут воспринимать русскоязычный Stackoverflow всерьез. Если вы действительно разбираетесь в теме, как насчет того, чтобы написать лучший ответ: возможно, он выйдет вперед по плюсам?

Я бы сказал, однострочный бесполезный ответ это определенно **не нормально**, но столь же ненормально жаловаться на плагиат однострочного бесполезного ответа из комментария. Тем не менее, это не означает разрешение копировать все подряд из комментариев. Если бы кто-то скопировал действительно полноценный ответ (который тянет на достаточную степень оригинальности), опубликованный в комментариях, без ссылки на источник, это уже нарушение правил. Комментарии так же, как и ответы, публикуются под лицензией Creative Commons с обязательным указанием авторства. Ответ, полностью состоящий из копии чужого текста без своего вклада, также должен быть отмечен общим. Ответы, нарушающие эти правила, должны быть удалены, а их авторы, при повторных нарушениях, забанены.

Comment: Почему ответ, скопированный из комментария, является нарушением? Комментарии вообще не предназачены для ответов.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Если указан автор и ссылка на источник и ответ сделан общим, не является. Да, не предназначены, но в комментариях часто пишут ответы-предположения, когда отвечающий не уверен, что его решение подходит. В этом случае, если ответ все же оказался правильным, но автор по какой-то причине не перенес его в ответ, будет некрасиво просто скопировать его без указания первоначального автора.

Comment: Так если автор "не уверен", то в чём вопрос? Или просто автор уверен, но не захотел получать или терять репутацию, неважно. Это осознанный выбор "комментатора" писать ответ в комментарий, нарушая правила, и не получать (или терять) репутацию, но почему другие обязаны ссылаться на него? И особенно для меня странна мысль, что именно ответы должны быть удалены (не комментарии!) и авторов ответов надо банить, почему?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Я же написал в ответе почему: условия лицензии требуют этого. Это чисто юридический аспект. Удалять и банить - потому что это единственный известный способ заставить правила работать. Можно также удалять и ответы в комментариях (на некоторых гуманитарных сайтах SE так и делают).

Comment: А где именно написано, что нельзя копировать ответы с комментариев? Я не вижу чтобы что-то такое было описано в справке. Вы видели хотя бы один такой прецедент в данной сети (чтобы удалялся ответ, потому что копирует комментарий)? Я, к примеру, нет. И эта лицензия, насколько я понимаю, распространяется на копирование информации куда-то на внешний сайт, но не внутри него.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Внизу сайта: "*пользовательское содержимое попадает под действие лицензии cc by-sa 3.0 с указанием ссылки на источник*". Исключения для комментариев нет. Исключения для копирования внутри сайта нет. Более подробно юридическим языком это описано в условиях использования (https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) в разделе Subsriber Content.

Answer (score -3):

Нет, это плохо.

Answer (score -3):

Да