# Нет перевода плашки на заблокированных вопросах

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, заблокированные-вопросы

[Нормально, когда ответ из одного слова набирает 4 балла?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9441/15479)

> [image: Скриншот]

Сообщение:

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. A link to a chat room will be posted in the comments below if the conversation was moved to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12745

Пока добавил перевод:

> Сообщение заблокировано из-за большого количества комментариев не по теме. Ссылка на чат будет размещена в комментариях ниже, если разговор был перенесён в чат.