# Стоит ли отвечать на вопрос где все отвечено в комментариях?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, ответы

Часто мне попадаются вопросы, где все написано в комментариях. Например - [этот вопрос-дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873617/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-nextline-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82). Почему он не закрыт, или почему там нет ответа? Или вопрос, где ответ в комментариях решил проблему. И вроде там ответили в комментариях, проблема решена(скорее всего), но вопрос остается открытым.

Мой вопрос - стоит ли отвечать на вопрос, где все уже решили в комментариях?

Comment: Вам поможет вот эта тема: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061

Comment: А  [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/873648/213987) не стоило перетаскивать из комментариев в ответ, а стоило закрыть вопрос как "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях."

Comment: И вот ещё связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4670/213987

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вопрос - явный дубликат, и вам нечего добавить - отвечать на него не надо. А не закрыт он потому что еще не успели.

Если вопрос - нормальный, то отвечать на него надо. Даже если все уже решили в комментариях, потому что комментарии не являются ответом на вопрос.