# Давайте почистим список "Без Единого Ответа"?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, закрытие-вопросов

Проблема, как вижу её я, заключается в этом (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers):

[image: screenshot]

Я не считаю себя перфекционистом или кем-то ещё, но просто эти вопросы которые находятся в топе — это неразгребаемая куча, которая мешает добраться до реальных задач.

[Вот что говорит Meta Stack Exchange по этому поводу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments):

> For comments that solve the problem or answer the question in the best way, the polite thing to do would be to notify the author using a comment reply (@Username), and prompt them to post their comment as an answer.
>
> If they follow up, great! Reward their ideas and helpfulness with an upvote, and accept the answer.
>
> If they don't follow up within a reasonable period of time, you can post an answer yourself with the solution that worked, giving proper attribution to the ideas.

**Что я предлагаю?**
Пройтись по этим вопросам и выполнить описанное выше, а может кто свои ответы найдет да оформит как следует.

1. Найти комментарий ответ
2. Написать следующее сообщение:

> *@user оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ*

3. Если в течении 3-х дней ответа нет, сформировать его самому используя комментарий, или же свой вариант.
4. Опционально можно написать второй комментарий:

> *@user согласно с мнением сообщества StackOverflow чтобы помочь сообществу легче находить информацию я использую Ваш коментарий за основу для ответа*

**Почему я создал этот вопрос?**
Как бы "тебе мешает ты и делай" очень хороший аргумент, но я один, а вопросов 6 тысяч, а мы же вроде как комьюнити, может кто и найдется кто поддержит/поможет =)

Comment: Поддерживаю, тоже об этом думал. Может быть, можно даже как-то автоматизировать этот процесс

Comment: Напоминать про перенос комментария в ответ, если автор не появлялся на сайте больше месяца - бесполезно, ИМХО. Лучше сразу перенести и сделать "общим".

Comment: Мне показывает "49,479 вопросов без единого ответа". Почему вам только 6,140?

Comment: @Kromster  скрин сделан на странице метки [tag:javascript].

Comment: На самом деле можно было ничего не писать, а сразу свой ответ делать. Плюс уже было обсуждение про ответы в комментариях: [Ответ на вопрос, взятый у другого пользователя из комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/186999)

Comment: Всем спасибо, насчёт напоминания согласен можно оформлять как "общий" сразу. И да, изначально этот вопрос относился чисто к js.

Comment: А можно как-то фильтровать этот список вопросов без ответов по тегам?

Comment: Конечно. Открываете [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags), выбираете нужную Вам, например [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) и переходите в таб ["Без принятого ответа"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/html)

Answer (score 2):

**Вопросы оставлять.**

- Во-первых, неправильно заданный вопрос (когда вопрос никто не
  комментирует и не отвечает) – это половина непонимания того, что ты
  "копаешь" в не правильном направлении.
- Во-вторых, есть "специфичные" вопросы, на которые может ответить
  один-два человека из 150 миллионов. Так сказать вопросы не на
  широкого потребителя и понятно что ответ приходит через года.
- В-третьих, неправильно заданный вопрос все равно воскреснет як жар
  птица. Потому что люди все-таки думают иногда похоже и похоже
  ошибаются :3

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд проблема не такая простая, какой вы ее описываете.
Посмотрим первый вопрос. "Как настроить что-то там". Хорошо, *username* попросили.
Но остальные вопросы! Там нет в комментариях ни одного ответа.
Например вопрос по среду разработки.*У меня не появляется галочка*. И таких куча. Там вопросы, порождающие обсуждение, а не конкретные ответы. По существу, их **закрывать** надо.

[Вопрос вообще без комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533608/jsoup-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
Отсюда я делаю вывод, что такое решение проблемы не подходит.

> Имхо, вопрос из разряда: "Мой компьютер убивает третью уборщицу подряд. Системный блок открыт, оттуда торчат оголённые провода, которые разбросаны по всей комнате, я их аккуратно обхожу, а уборщицы этого не делают. Вопрос, Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при смерти очередной уборщицы, не воняло и при этом, было чисто? Ещё напрягает то что я деньги перечисляю по предоплате, а умирают они все до того как наводят порядок."

Comment: Подобные вопросы нужно закрывать, я имел ввиду вопросы которые конкретно имеют ответ, но в комментариях, так что не согласен что "данное решение проблемы не подходит"

Comment: Вы предлагаете сообществу ручками проверять каждый вопрос без ответа?

Comment: я начал это делать и понял, что так это не работает

Comment: Ммм, ну как бы да

Comment: А Вы предлагаете "ручками" закрывать вопросы?

Comment: **я не говорю, что знаю решение**. Может, отделять машиной вопросы с залайкаными комментами

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, неактивные вопросы с нулем голосов автоматически удаляются системой, через какое-то время