# Копипаст комментария в ответ без указания авторства - допустимо или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, нормы-поведения

Вот [участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398230/joker?tab=answers). Зарегистрировался сегодня, опубликовал 22 ответа за 2 часа.

Если я правильно посчитал, 16 из 22 ответов - скопированы из комментариев к вопросам. Еще один [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153305/215103) скопирован с википедии.

С остальными 5 ответами все нормально. (
[1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153282/215103)
[2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153286/215103)
[3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153290/215103)
[4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153291/215103)
[5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153300/215103)
)

Ответы почти все скопированы дословно, все - без указания источника, и не сделаны "общими" (community wiki).

---

Попросил в комментариях указывать источник. Получил ответ, что [лицензия](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) якобы не обязывает это делать (а это не так).

---

Повесил кастомный флаг на один из ответов, в котором объяснил ситуацию. Флаг был отклонен, в причине - ссылки на мету: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4670/), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/).

По первой ссылке - предлагают дополнять комментарий до ответа, а не копипастить его дословно. По второй ссылке - предлагают еще вариант: копировать дословно, но с превращением ответа в "общий", что сделано не было.

---

Считаю, что ответы надо сделать общими, а автору - "помассировать копчик" (с).

---

Задал вопрос на мета-мете (в первую очередь про лицензию): [If a user copies content from another SO post into his own post verbatim, is the attribution required according to the license?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350905/353058)

Консенсус - лицензия действует и на комментарии тоже, действия автора нарушают лицензию.

---

**UPD:**

Появился [еще один пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398755/jokerbot). Зарегистрирован сегодня, ведет себя так же, и даже ник похожий. 27 ответов примерно за час, похоже опять все скопированы из комментариев.

[Третий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/399631/jokerbot-v2) аккаунт, и [четвертый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/401315/bog).

У 2 из 4 в профилях прямо написано, что это боты.

---

<s>[Еще один аккаунт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/403078/mmm)</s> Удален, видимо модератором.

Comment: Флаг был отклонён мной и поднятая тема весьма интересная по двум причинам: а) описывается весьма давний консенсус б) вопрос никогда не ставился в плоскости указания источника (поэтому не считаю, что есть смысл закрывать тему дубликатом)

Comment: @AK Со старым консенсусом я согласен, но там решили, что ответы нужно в таком случае делать "общими", или дополнять, а он этого не делает. Выглядит так, что он просто репутацию фармит.

Comment: Моральную оценку ("фармит") я давать не готов, т.к. вижу, что участники делают некоторую работу, притом ту, которую другие не делают. И сложно сказать: если более пяти ответов в сутки - это уже фарминг? А шести? Я и сам порой  пролетая над интересным вопросом вытаскивал из комментов. А став модератором могу сказать, что наблюдал что бывает как после создания ответа комментарии маркируются как "неактуальные" и их удаляют. Поэтому мне весьма интересен именно вопрос в заголовке, уточнение про авторство. Как с этим дела в 2020 году? Де факто редко кто делал ответы общими - это совет, не требование

Comment: Еще мне про лицензию интересно. По идее ведь без разницы, копировать контент на на другой сайт, или на сам SO - нужно указывать авторство.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, наоборот, решили что не нужно делать общими.

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно ссылку? Я подробно не читал, но в топовом ответе написано наоборот: [*"Переносить ответ в ответ и отмечать "общим", либо улучшать и дополнять"*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3069/215103).

Comment: Работая по основной работе в академическом учреждении, я привык относиться к плагиату крайне отрицательно. Здесь стараюсь этот вопрос не поднимать, но когда такое происходит - ну, мягко говоря, отвечающий очень теряет в моих глазах и вызывает раздражение. Что, трудно хотя бы переписать своими словами? Указать честно - ответ не мой (хотя читающие и так это видят)? Согласен с @HolyBlackCat на 120% - за такие вещи - дословно переписанный из комментариев чужой ответ - надо массировать копчик...

Comment: + вопросу, но не согласен с решением автора.

Comment: [Спросил на мета-мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350905/353058) про лицензию.

Comment: @AlexF Сомневаюсь. У нас верхний ответ - "ничего не делать", видимо это не кажется проблемой. Тормошить модераторов, чтобы они подчинились лицензии, как-то не хочется.

Comment: Возможно, кто-то опробует бота. Нейросети в действии.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Непонятно, почему с разных аккаунтов. Мы что, заминусили первый до бана на ответы? Думал, что кто-то хочет с них плюсы набивать, но оба пользователя считаются "незарегистрированными" и не могут голосовать...

Comment: Интересное замечание: когда наводишь справа от любого комментария - лицензия пишется, а когда нажимаешь на кнопку с таймлайном https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10628/timeline, то там у комментариев лицензии нет :)

Comment: По поводу второго пользователя - ну если модераторы явно указывают, что это корректное поведение, то как же не появиться новым плагиаторам?...

Comment: @Harry Думаю это тот же человек, ник уж очень похожий.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А я думаю хуже — бот (судя по нику и тому что он вроде не комментирует, а только отвечает).

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Возможно. Тут еще мелькал `jokerbot_v2`, так у него в "о себе" чейнджлог был. :)

Comment: И что модераторы бездействуют?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Про этот аккаунт я вроде не писал, не уверен.

Comment: Четвёртый бот, V3 кажется. Тут ещё такой взгляд на "моральный ушерб" от его действий. Это бот с незарегестрированной учёткой, ему все плюса/минуса до лампочки, и "убрать за собой" он тоже не собирается. Теперь, в выходной, нормальные участники тратят своё время проверяя его посты в очередях проверок и вне них. Когда кто-то по незнанию запостил низкокачественный ответ и на него было потрачено время - это нормально, но когда это делается умышленно автоматом, то встаёт вопрос о правомерности такого рода действий: "Скучаете? Сейчас найду вам, чем занятся".

Comment: @0xdb Вот вот. Хотелось бы какой-то ответ от модераторов получить, а то они пока в основном пожимают плечами, и расставляют указание авторства в ответ на кастомные флаги.

Comment: Может немного усилить "ограничение новичка"? Ну или снимать эти ограничния когда уровень репы побольше. Сейчас они снимаются на 10 репы. Это же всего лишь один плюс. Т.е. боту поставят один плюс, и он сможет плодить псевдоответы в промышленных масштабах. Этот один плюс может быть и от создателя самого бота. А если нужно будет больше плюсов, то создателю бота нужно будет плюсануть больше ответов бота, а тогда модераторы смогут его спалить. Модераторы ведь видят кто голосовал?

Comment: @EOF *"Модераторы ведь видят кто голосовал?"* Вроде нет. Не понимаю, почему просто не банить такие аккаунты...

Comment: Так банить их можно будет вечно. Тут нужно думать как усложнить ботам жизнь. (Дух сообщества, я не про тебя:))

Comment: @EOF Их не так много, банить вручную не проблема, имхо. Плюс есть баны по IP/подсетям.

Answer (score 17):

Базовые принципы работы сайта:

1. Любому вопросу должного качества должен в конечном счете нужен ответ.
2. Любой полезный труд должен вознаграждаться.

Отсюда сразу же следует, что нет ничего плохого или постыдного в переносе информации в ответы из комментариев, как и в сборе репутации за счёт этих действий.

Но тут есть тонкость: это должен быть именно труд. Комментарий и ответ - это разные форматы сообщений с разными требованиями к ним, и если бы сообщение подходило под формат ответа - вряд ли автор написал его комментарием. В частности, комментарий из одного предложения - это норма, а вот ответ из одного предложения довольно редко можно признать качественным, разве что когда автор что-то совсем библиотечное спрашивает.

Так что прямой копи-паст без обработки недопустим независимо от указания авторства.

Comment: Существуют комментарии, которые достаточны для ответов. Например, вопрос *"какую функцию использовать для X?"* и комментарий *"используйте функцию Y для этого"*. Так что "прямой копи-паст без обработки недопустим независимо от указания авторства." — слишком сильное утверждение

Answer (score 8):

Чтобы выбрать комментарий с ответом, надо разбираться в теме и понимать, что ты переносишь в ответ. Ну и если человек ходит и выискивает такие вопросы, то это тоже требует определённых усилий. Я не считаю, что он в таком случае обязан помечать ответ общим. Человек, написавший вместо ответа комментарий, намеренно отказался от репутации, а тот, кто перенёс, хочет её получить.

Что касается указания ссылки на автора, у всего свои пределы. Вот есть [ответ](//stackoverflow.com/a/19255268/4928642), что на питоне для извлечения квадратного корня надо возвести число в степень `0.5`. Мне теперь на каждое извлечение корня в своём коде вешать ссылку на этот ответ? А если кто-то спросит, как называется стандартная функция для вывода на консоль, а другой ответит, то на каждый её вызов? Должны же быть какие-то разумные лимиты. На мой взгляд, эта грань где-то около "я полностью понимаю, как работает этот код и способен написать аналогичный самостоятельно".

Comment: *"Чтобы выбрать комментарий с ответом, надо разбираться в теме"* Нуу, не факт. Если я вижу коммент "Используйте X.", то это уже выглядит для меня как ответ, даже если я не знаю, что такое X. *"указания ссылки на автора ... стандартная функция для вывода на консоль"* Я такого не говорил. Здесь человек копипастит не названия функций, а комментарии целиком, *дословно*. Это уже верх лени.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 1. Это _X_ вовсе не обязательно является ответом на вопрос. Скопипастив это в ответ, ты утверждаешь, что оно оно является, а написав в комментарии, лишь предполагаешь, что оно может помочь. Как перемножить 2 числа из 100 десятичных цифр? Используй джаву. - Ну как, годится на роль ответа? А на роль комментария - вполне. 2. А я и не говорил, что ты такое говорил. Это просто пример.

Answer (score 6):

Комментарии нужны лишь для того, чтобы уточнить какие-то нюансы и т.п. SE в целом продвигают идею, что после нахождение ответа комментарии нужно удалять.

Так что, смотрите на ситуацию так, будто комментариев не было вовсе. Посему:

1. Создавать ответ на базе комментариев допустимо.
2. Авторство можно не указывать, это правил не нарушает. Указание авторства лишь рекомендация и правило хорошего тона.
3. Нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы "фармить репутацию" (:

Почитал MSE. Там рекомендуют добавлять текст об оригинальном авторе.

1. [What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251/260198).
2. [Is it in bad form to answer a question with another user's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64140/260198).
3. [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/260198)

Comment: *"Авторство можно не указывать, это правил не нарушает."* А лицензию разве не нарушает?

Comment: Фармить репутацию - действительно не плохо, но когда это делают этично. А не плагиатом.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat насколько я понимаю, лицензия относится больше к ответам/вопросам. Комментарии считаются лишь временным явлением.

Comment: Относится ко всему, что постит участник: ["all publicly accessible user contributions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Не совсем согласен, что относится ко всему. Если посмотреть таймлайн любого поста, то там стоит упоминание о текушей лицензии, но не для комментариев.  По ссылке в вашем комментарии выше - _for the content I post_, то есть содержание того, что я публикую. Но комментарием я ничего не публикую, я комментирую то, что публикуют другие.

Comment: @0xdb Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) написано точнее: "all text ... that you provide to the public Network". Но дело не в лицензии, а в принципе. Человек ну явно набивает репутацию плагиатом - а мы ничего не делаем? На английском SO ему бы уже давно банхамерром прилетело.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik у лицензии нигде не прописано сроков действия, а во всплывашке у даты коммента эта самая лицензия явно указана

Comment: С другой стороны, можно попытаться приплести [«порог оригинальности»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) — достаточно ли содержательны комменты, чтобы вообще начинать считать их объектами авторского права?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat По поводу, что там или сям написано, не буду спорить, я не юрист. Пока было, и  надеюсь так и останется - комментарий не является ответом. Почему я питаю такую надежду? Если я ищу решение по малознакомой для меня теме, то я хочу найти исчерпывающий, хорошо оформленный  ответ. Если такой не находится и для решения надо обработать десяток комментариев под вопросом, мелким шрифтом, с не форматированным кодом, со ссылками ведущими в никуда, то я плачу.

Comment: Комментарий ответом не является. Но ответ, дословно копирующий комментарий, без указания автора - это уже не цитирование, а плагиат. Причем откровенно глупый. Лучше предложить в комментариях автору комментария превратить свой комментарий в ответ - это и законно, и *морально*. Здесь все почему-то пытаются апеллировать к юридической стороне дела (да и юридически плагиат незаконен), забывая о моральной - при этом не отрицая принципы "не быть излишне раздражительным" и иже с ним, т.е. **сугубо моральные**! Там никак нельзя пригласить @joker почитать это обсуждение - пусть сам попытается понять..

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik [Это неверно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350906/692649).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings я не юрист. Подождём ответа от представителя компании, который наверняка скажет.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Вам не нужно быть адвокатом. Ясно. Там прямо сказано, что комментарии лицензированы. Конец истории!

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Не уверен, что мы дождемся оффициального ответа. Сотрудники компании могли тот пост вообще не заметить, или решить не отвечать, потому что нормальный ответ уже есть.

Comment: У модераторов нет какого-то другого канала связи с компанией?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну есть чат. Спрошу завтра.

Answer (score 5):

Как мне кажется, история с публикацией ответов в комментариях начинается чуть ли не в первый день работы сайта. В прошлом, когда я активно модерировал Stack Overflow на русском, я публиковал комментарий с просьбой перенести информацию из комментария в ответ. (К слову, на ХэшКоде у модераторов была возможность преобразовывать комментарий в ответ без участия автора, но с сохранением авторства.) Довольно часто я получал отказ с фразой вроде «если хотите, можете сами опубликовать комментарий ответом». Я вижу несколько причин этому. На мой взгляд, две главные из них:

1. *Отвечающие делают акцент на помощи автору вопроса здесь и сейчас.* База знаний как таковая может не быть их приоритетом. В этом случае различие между комментарием и ответом в их глазах минимально.
2. *Отвечающие имеют личный стандарт качества своих ответов.* Случается, что у участников есть время на то, чтобы поделится минимальными знаниями, чтобы решить задачу, а на полноценный ответ, который удовлетворял бы их лично — нет.

Кроме того, [в одном из ранних видео про Stack Overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ) Джоэл Спольски рассказывал как «разработчики сайта» видят лучший способ новому участнику набрать репутацию на сайте. Стратегия сводится к отысканию вопросов, в которых лучшие ответы можно дополнить. Механика проста — исходный ответ берется за основу, дорабатывается и публикуется в том же вопросе как авторский, не общий.

В результате, на мой взгляд, нет ничего страшного в публикации комментария другого участника своим авторским ответом, особенно если:

1. автор комментария явно выражает отсутствие желания делать комментарий ответом сам и…
2. комментарий является достаточным ответом или…
3. автор ответа, основанного на комментарии, расписывает решение более подробно (как с технической, так и с литературной точки зрения).

Comment: (3) здесь не происходит, комментарии копировались дословно. (1) тоже не происходит, авторам комментариев не предлагали самим запостить ответы. (2) - тут по-разному. Есть [плохие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1154755/215103), если [хорошие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153291/215103). Ощущение, что человек не особо следил за качеством комментов, которые копировал.

Comment: В принципе я согласен, что в перенос комментов в ответы может быть полезен. Но когда бо́льшая часть действий пользователя - это просто дословное копирование комментариев, с огромной скоростью (около 2-3 минут на ответ, вроде бы) - это кажется странным.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Когда я, как модератор, просматривал действия участников (при обработке тревог, например), я старался оценивать действия больше с точки зрения пользы для сообщества и нашей базы знаний. Второй пункт — ручная работа против скриптов. Как результат, если действия полезны, если делается вручную (читайте «осознанно и внимательно») и не нарушают лицензию, то почему бы и нет?

Comment: Но ведь в этой ситуации лицезия нарушается? Авторство не указано.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, согласен, в таком случае хорошо бы связаться с участником. Возможно он / она просто не знает, что (и как) следует указывать автора комментария.

Comment: Я [просил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153314/215103) автора указывать авторство; он почему-то считает, что лицензия этого не требует. Возможно будет лучше, если модератор напишет.

Comment: Объявился уже четвертый аккаунт с такой манерой поведения. У 2 из 4 в профилях написано, что это боты. Видимо кто-то экспериментирует. Что лучше делать, вешать флаг? Или проходить мимо?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Проверять очередь сообщений низкого качества с включенным фильтром "Ответы". Большинство сообщений от bog'а уже туда попало (автоматически), так что их можно снести без участия модераторов.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Хочется какой-то официальный ответ получить. Ответы сносить можно, но человеку ничего не мешает продолжать постить новые.

Answer (score 4):

Напишу свое мнение ответом:

Все ответы, скопированные дословно из комментариев, нужно сделать "общими". Или вставить в них ссылку на комментарий, откуда взят текст. А лучше и то, и другое.

Автору нужно обяснить, что он должен делать это сам в будущем.

---

Конечно, если автор написал ответ *на основе* комментария, и дополнил его чем-то своим, то все нормально, и "общим" его делать не нужно. Но здесь такого не было.

---

На мета-мете похожий [консенсус](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do): (ссылка из соседнего ответа)

> In the context of Stack Exchange sites, any copying and pasting of any amount of text or code that wasn't written by you is plagiarism if you try, explicitly or implicitly, to pass it off as your own work.

"На SO плагиат - это копипаст любого текста или кода, который написали не вы, если вы пытаетесь явно или неявно выдать его за то, что создано вами."

> You may not be aware of this, but plagiarism is considered a grave infraction in academic and professional circles around the globe, and it can lead to dire consequences if discovered.

"Возможно вы этого не знаете, но плагиат считается серьезным нарушением в академических и профессиональных кругах по всему миру, и пойманному на плагиате угрожают серьезные последствия."

> It is possible that moderators suspend you, or delete some of your content if plagiarism has been discovered.

"Модераторы могут забанить вас, или удалить некоторые из ваших постов, если вас поймали на плагиате."

Comment: "In the context of Stack Exchange sites, any copying and pasting of any amount of text or code that wasn't written by you is plagiarism if you try, explicitly or implicitly, to pass it off as your own work." => если я переписал руками текст ответа, а не использовал буфер обмена, то это не является плагиатом. Так как выяснить, как именно участник это сделал сложно, дальнейшие рассуждения с таким определением плагиата бессмысленны.

Comment: К тому же по ссылкам в моём ответе другой "консенсус" (принятый ответ), а значит ни то, ни другое консенсусом не является, потому что мнения разные. Кстати, изначально по [вашей ссылке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077) ТС говорил про копипаст с других сайтов, а по [моей](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1886) - конкретно про перенос комментариев в ответы.

Comment: Никакого "или" не может быть, ссылка на источник обязательна, это требование лицензии.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight смотрите комментарий под моим ответом

Answer (score 4):

Кому интересно, я накидал флагов на наиболее ужасные сообщения, где скопированные комментарии не отвечали на вопрос или были малосодержательными. Часть из них удалили модераторы, часть удалилась по результатам проверки в очереди. Далее, я отправил жалобу через форму обратной связи:

[image: support request]

Ответ:

[image: support responce]

То есть, определенного ответа, что участник нарушает, не дали. Но участник больше не публикует новых ответов (возможно, улетел в автоматическую блокировку за минусы).

Comment: В блокировку он не улетел)

Answer (score 3):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268

> We discussed this on meta.serverfault a short while ago and decided
> that you should [Steal comments that answer the question and post them
> as an answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931). You can always tick the Community Wiki box if you're not
> comfortable earning reputation for someone else's work.

Вольный перевод:

> Мы обсуждали это на мете недавно и решили, что следует перемещать
> комментарии, которые отвечают на вопрос, в ответы. Вы всегда
> **можете** пометить такие ответы общими, **если вас не устраивает** получение репутации за чужую работу.

Некоторая мотивация из [другого принятого ответа](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931):

> If it happens enough either the misguided commentators will be annoyed
> enough at the "lost" rep to give outright answers next time, or no one
> will notice / care and you'll help the community and... oh yeah, get
> some rep.

Вольный перевод:

> Если <такое перемещение комментария в ответ> будет происходить
> достаточно часто, подобные комментаторы будут недовольны потерей
> репутации и в следующий раз дадут действительно ответы <а не
> комментарии>, либо никто не заметит/никого не будет волновать
> <что ответ состоит из комментария>, и вы поможете сообществу и получите
> немного репутации.

Не вижу ничего аморального в этом. Участник не указывал явно, что это его контент. А получение репутации за такие ответы, как видно по цитатам выше, не запрещено.

В будущем такие комментарии могут быть удалены за сроком давности, зато информация в виде ответа останется. Но про это уже подробно написал @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik.

Comment: *Участник не указывал явно, что это его контент.* А вор, типа, и не говорит, что несет свою сумку, а не полную наворованного добра - так что ж тут такого? Забавно, кстати, что подобной позиции придерживаются "западники", свихнувшиеся на авторских правах.

Comment: @Harry вы не имеете право называть человека вором, пока это не доказано, иначе это может расцениваться как клевета. А чтобы это доказать, надо привести конкретно цитаты из лицензии, которая относится к комментариям, что автор комментария является его законным владельцем и тот, кто переносит, обязан указывать это авторство.

Comment: @AlexF не вижу логики в вашем комментарии. Почему ценность сайта падает, если появляется новый ответ? Если не у кого будет копировать, т.е. все ответы будут в ответах, а не в комментариях, то и перенос не нужен будет...

Comment: @AlexF подождите, а зачем тогда вы даёте ответы вообще? Ответы даются, чтобы люди их копировали к себе в код. Если вы имеете в виду копирование вашего **ответа** другим участником в виде своего **ответа**, то тут речь не об этом, тут речь о переносе **комментария** в **ответ**, учитывая что сам комментатор этого не сделал.

Comment: Казуистика и демагогия для оправдания воровства... Никогда бы не подумал, что такое возможно в приличном обществе, да еще и с обвинениями в клевете за то, что называешь плагиатора - плагиатором...

Comment: @Harry хм, отсутствие аргументов и обвинения в демагогии без доказательств для оправдания лени в написании вопроса вместо комментария? Мы здесь вроде бы вопрос обсуждаем, а не пытаемся оскорблять, обвинять в воровстве и так далее.

Comment: @AlexF я нигде не говорил, что ответы этого участника улучшают качество контента комментариев...

Comment: @AlexF я karmik, но это не относится к обсуждению всё равно.

Comment: @AlexF эти слова говорят ровно то, что говорят: информация, которая была в **комментарии**, перенесена в **ответ**. **Комментарии** могут быть перенесены в чат или удалены модератором по причине "Он больше не нужен.", а **ответ**, содержащий контент этого **комментария** останется (если такой **ответ** не будет удалён по другим причинам). Не вижу тут ничего про "улучшение качества".

Comment: Решение на мете не может переопределить лицензию, так как она является юридическим документом. Лицензия требует указывать автора при использовании любых материалов, для комментариев исключения нет, ссылку на правила уже кинули в комментарии под вопросом. Так что "steal" нельзя. Репа тут вообще непричем.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight пожалуйста, приведите цитату из лицензии, которая обязывает указывать автора при любом использовании материалов. В attribution написано про указание лицензий, имён и так далее при их наличии, причём "You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use."

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight собственно в моём понимании это указание лицензии и псевдонима при явном указании о необходимости этого самим автором комментария. То есть если автор комментария указывает copyright notice, например, то тогда ты обязан указывать его авторство, иначе - нет.

Comment: @karmik Да, имя автора нужно указывать только при его наличии. Его может не быть (например, учетная запись удалена), тогда указывать не нужно. Сам автор не обязан ничего указывать, достаточно того, что отображает сайт. Раньше было подробное объяснение, как именно лицензия применима к материалам на сайте, но теперь его почему-то снесли.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ну если вы приведёте это объяснение (сам я не юрист, так что не разбираюсь в этом) или документ, где чёрным по белому будет написано что обязательно указание авторства при любом использовании, то соглашусь. Более того, придётся переделывать кучу кода на проектах, где code snippets взяты со стековерфлоу, если это действительно так.

Comment: @karmik Вы сами его привели - пункт a.1.A. Соглашаться или нет - ваше дело, но бан за плагиат вам могут прописать независимо от этого.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в том что я привёл (section 3, a.1.A) "designated to receive attribution" для меня означает "автор указал что надо указывать его авторство". Объяснение, что такое "designated" не нашёл в документе. Надо понимать правильное толкование этих правил. В любом случае я буду согласным с правилами, независимо от правильной трактовки.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight и, кстати, если это действительно так, то все обсуждения на английской и нашей мете и конкретно это обсуждение не имеют смысла.

Comment: @karmik Мне добавить нечего - по моей трактовке, тот факт, что рядом с комментарием отображается имя автора, уже достаточно для designated. Если нужен точный ответ, пишите в форму обратной связи, там должны перенаправить вопрос юристам компании.

Answer (score 2):

[НАРУШЕНИЕ АВТОРСКИХ ПРАВ В ИНТЕРНЕТЕ. ПРОБЛЕМЫ ДОКАЗАТЕЛЬСТВА ПЛАГИАТА В ИНТЕРНЕТЕ](http://www.aski.ru/ru/news/id-505/)

> С появлением и функционированием Всемирной (Глобальной) сети у
> некоторых ее пользователей возникает иллюзия, что поскольку она
> общедоступна, то и ее контент никому не принадлежит, что совершенно
> неверно. Публикация в Интернете отличается от публикации в журнале или
> другом издании только формой, носителем информации. И в том и в другом
> случае имеется автор, который создал в результате своего
> интеллектуального труда произведение. Присвоение чужого труда и
> получение выгоды за этот счет или, может быть, и не получение никакой
> материальной выгоды является нарушением закона независимо от того, на
> каком носителе опубликована информация.

Сайты должны внимательно отвечать на жалобы про плагиат, например как на vk:
[Как пожаловаться на плагиат?](https://vk.com/faq12567)

> ## Как пожаловаться на плагиат?
>
> Появилась возможность
> пожаловаться на плагиат. Откройте меню записи с помощью иконки в
> правом верхнем углу публикации. Затем нажмите на кнопку «Пожаловаться»
> и выберите в качестве причины «Неоригинальный контент». Для
> подтверждения настоящего источника обязательно укажите ссылку на
> оригинальную запись. Мы рассмотрим обращение и примем меры в случае
> необходимости.

С данным грубым нарушением ( полным копированием ) совета другого пользователя вижу только удаление ответа или с навязыванием писать авторство совета.