# Правка или ответ?

Tags: обсуждение

Положим участник написал в ответ на питоне:

```
def not_zero(x):
    if x:
        return 1
    return 0
# ...
```

Ну, мне сразу ясно, что функция `not_zero` вообще не нужна — она просто дублирует функционал
`bool`. И я пишу второй ответ где все также, только заменил эту функцию на бул. И получаю плюс.

...И *два* минуса

Ответ удаляю, тому участнику делаю правку (которую до этого откатил т.к. тогда у нас ответы становились одинаковые). И думаю:

> ## Как быть в таких случаях?
>
> Вносить ли таким участникам правку и/или писать в комменты или писать (полу-)свой ответ?

Что и предлагаю обсудить...

**P.S.** [тот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160959/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b-8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81/1160966?noredirect=1#comment2013522_1160966)

Comment: все ответы плохие, надо все заминусовать. В правилах четко указано, что не надо редактировать так, чтобы менялся смысл.

Comment: Написали плохие ответы, очевидно

Comment: например тем, что это не ответы, а просто блоки кода, неизвестно как связанные с вопросом, неизвестно чем отличающиеся от кода в вопросе. В одном из которых еще и зачем-то в одну строчку все впихнуто ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Тот, где в одну строчку я сделал для прикола и удалил, а остальные нормальные ответы — да, просто блоки кода "без циклов".

Comment: Как можно догадаться, что они действительно "без циклов"? Может они вообще удаляют все файлы и папки на компьютере. А такие вредоносные ответы - нужно удалять. Если не ошибаюсь, то ты ратовал и за удаление пользователей, которые их оставляют ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Эти ответы удаляют? — нет. Они отвечают на вопрос — да. Циклов нет — задачу решают. Уотс ронг? **P.S.** `А такие вредоносные ответы - нужно удалять. `  — Удаляйте себе на здоровье, только эти ответы вредоносными не являются. Я не понимаю что с ними не так?

Comment: _Эти ответы удаляют? — нет._ - просто потому, что решили такие не удалять

Comment: _Они отвечают на вопрос — да_ - чем ты это можешь доказать? Это просто какой-то код, непонятно что делающий

Comment: _Циклов нет — задачу решают._ - докажи, что циклов нет?

Comment: _только эти ответы вредоносными не являются._ - почему не являются? Кусок кода, который непонятно что делает - докажи что он не вредоносный

Comment: @Grundy `Они отвечают на вопрос — да - чем ты это можешь доказать? Это просто какой-то код, непонятно что делающий ` — один из ответов принят, другой получил несколько плюсов => сообщество и автор вопроса решили, что таки отвечает.

Comment: `Циклов нет — задачу решают. - докажи, что циклов нет?` — код не включает ключевые слова `for` и `while`.

Comment: _один из ответов принять_ - принятие в качестве ответа автором не доказывает ни полезность ни правильность, автор может поставить галочку на любой ответ

Comment: _другой получил несколько плюсов => сообщество и автор вопроса решили, что таки отвечает_ - либо просто сговорились с несколькими участниками и модераторам необходимо проверить, не нарушаются ли правила голосований

Comment: _код не включает ключевые слова for и while_ может они включают другие ключевые слова так же относящиеся к циклам.

Comment: @Grundy Это задание по учебе — не имеет значения используется ли цикл потом при исполнении. Главное, что в коде его нет.

Comment: _Это задание по учебе_ - это никак не должно влиять на ответ

Comment: это что, троллинг такой оригинальный? Я вам вообще не обязан ничего доказывать... что вы хотите от меня услышать ?

Comment: Я - ничего не хочу услышать. Ты спросил - что делать с такими ответами - я написал в комментариях что именно надо делать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111323/discussion-between-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica-and-grundy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как по мне, если правка явно улучшает качество вопроса и не изменяет его смысл, то надо делать правку, а если код надо написать по-другому, то зависит от объёма кода — если можно улучшить пару строк, то лучше написать об этом в комментарии, если же что-то большее, то дать свой ответ.

*Примеры явного улучшения без изменения смысла: участник сделал много опечаток => исправить их, участник написал какое-то слово не в той раскладке => перевести в нужную.*

Пример из вопроса скорее относится к небольшому изменению кода => надо указать в комментарии, что лучше использовать `bool`. В принципе, можно дать свой ответ, но желательно сослаться на первоначального автора, если изменения незначительны, а то посчитают за копипаст (см. [Копипаст комментария в ответ без указания авторства - допустимо или нет?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10628/398802)).