# Кажется, дух удаляет что-то лишнее

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, удаление-вопросов, дух-сообщества

[Вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1076639/178988) не является закрытым, он редактировался менее суток назад и под ним есть комментарии двух человек. По-моему, он не должен удаляться духом.

> [image: скриншот]

История изменений:

> [image: скриншот истории]

Комментарии:

> [image: скриншот комментариев]

PS: Я восстановил вопрос, но подозреваю, что он будет каждый день удаляться?

Comment: А много на сайте таких "давних" вопросов без ответов и заминусованные?

Comment: @EzioMercer, не знаю.

Comment: Просто может он всегда их удалял....

Comment: @EzioMercer, возможно, но по каким критериям? В любом случае, это нелогично.

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392) написано, что для удаления достаточно: 1) вопросу было более 30 дней, 2) рейтинг не выше -1, 3) нет ответов, 4) не заблокирован. Вроде бы все условия выполнены.

Comment: @wololo, а разве 30 дней не с момента последнего обновления должно быть?

Comment: Фразу `если вопросу более 30 дней`, я понимаю как, вопрос был задан более тридцати дней назад. А что имелось ввиду на самом деле, мне не известно. Но удалять автоматически сразу после редактирования, на мой взгляд, неправильно.

Comment: Кстати, сейчас вопрос снова удалён.

Comment: @wololo, Дух настойчивый... Восстановил. Поставь там плюсик - вроде с 0 не должно удаляться.

Comment: [Кхм...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZrdY.png)

Comment: @wololo, эх.. значит ещё кого-то надо. Получается, кроме нас никто не плюсовал...

Answer (score 2):

> Примечание от автора: этот ответ [был взят из комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/3069#3069) @wololo, поэтому был сделан [общим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

[Здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/) написано, что для удаления достаточно:

1. Вопросу было более `30` дней,
2. Рейтинг не выше `-1`,
3. Нет ответов,
4. Не заблокирован.

Все условия выполнены.

> Примечание: на данный момент (30.04.2023) вопрос восстановлен, и он не будет удалён через 30 дней, так как имеет рейтинг `1`.