# Что делает вариант "Оставить открытым" в очереди проверок "Голоса за закрытие"

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Подскажите пожалуйста, если я выбираю "Оставить открытым", то считается как то что я ничего не сделал или это учитывается потом как-то? Я в том плане, что если допустим 10 человек проголосуют за "Оставить открытым", а 5-о проголосуют за закрытие, то вопрос всё же закроют или из-за перевеса "Оставить открытым" вопрос останется открытым?

Ещё наверное порядок голосования может учитываться, если учитывается, то расскажите и об этом пожалуйста. И если всё же вариант "Оставить открытым" ничего не делает, то чем это отличается от бездействия или например того же "Пропустить"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если этот вопрос стоит задать на MSE, то скажите пожалуйста

Comment: при определенном количестве - прекращается голосование и вопрос остается открытым

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, напиши как ответ, пожалуйста, чтобы я его принял и вопрос был закрытым :)

Comment: А что у вас за тема оформления такая? Вроде не контраст и не тёмная...

Comment: @ΝNL993 Тёмная тема самого сайта + DarkReader. Иногда второе отключаю для SO, иногда включаю :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Примечание от автора: этот ответ [был взят из комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/3069#3069) @Grundy, поэтому был сделан [общим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

При определенном количестве - прекращается голосование и вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: можно было не делать общим

Comment: @Grundy я считаю, что так некрасиво делать. Поэтому опираюсь на это: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%83-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f#3069 Тем более, сообщество поддержало эту идею (31 голос "за" и только 2 "против")